# script to create a list based on conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a table that has, let's say 2 columns. `Column A` has *names*, `column B` has either *empty or non-empty cells*.

I want to create a separate list with `names` from column A *where the opposite cell in B is **empty***.

When I execute the code it doesn't bring any errors, however the list that is created in the output range is only with the name of the first person that has empty cell in front of him, i.e. that name appears 10 times in my output list.

Can anyone help me understand what's wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance!

This is the code that I have.

```js
function HLnames() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("HL test");
  var ind = 0;
  var fullRange = ss.getRange("A3:B26").getValues();
  var rangeList = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < fullRange.length; i++) {
    if (fullRange[i][1] === "") {
      rangeList.push(fullRange[i][0]);
      ind = ind + 1;
    }
  }
  var outputRange = ss.getRange(30, 1, ind, 1);
  outputRange.setValue(rangeList);
}
```

Comment: Not sure, but check value of `fullRange[i][1]`. It can be `undefined` or can have spaces `" "`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you should be using `setValues` instead of `setValue`. – [Google's Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object)).

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, puqeko! Tried that but now it brings up an error.